# How to remove hardware breakpoints properly

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, winapi, breakpoints

I am trying to create a small debugger with hardware breakpointing capabilities.
I use Vectored Exception Handling to catch the exceptions and I have encountered a problem when trying to remove breakpoints:

When the handler is resetting the Dr6 register there is a possibility that the breakpoint gets removed at the same time.
The handler is suspended and has it's context switched with the modified Dr7 register but when it exits the context is switched again with the Dr7 register in it's original state.

Unfortunately there is no way to synchronize the context switches since it occurs outside of the handler.

Is there a way to only change specific registers using `CONTEXT::ContextFlags`? Or perhaps some better approach to remove breakpoints in general?

**HANDLER:**

```
inline bool handle(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS* t_ExceptionInfo)
{
    if (m_index == 0xFF || t_ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode != STATUS_SINGLE_STEP || !(t_ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Dr6 & 1ui64 << m_index))
    {
        return false;
    }

    t_ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->ContextFlags |= CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;
    t_ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Dr6 = 0;
    return true;
}
```

**REMOVE:**

```
if (SuspendThread(hThread) != -1)
{
    CONTEXT ctx{ 0 };
    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;
    if (GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx))
    {
            ctx.Dr7 &= ~(1ui64 << m_index * 2);
            SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);
    }
    ResumeThread(hThread);
}
```

Comment: Why would thread context change between the calls if the thread is suspended?

Comment: I don't know about the error you encountered but you should use ```WaitForDebugEvent``` function instead, also can you clarify more by what do you mean when you say  ```resetting the Dr6 register there is a possibility that the breakpoint gets removed at the same time``` the breakpoint is per-thread context so if there is an entity that is running even if it is able to remove breakpoint from dr0-4 then it won't affect the thread your debugging, can you try to make it clear as the context switch doesn't affect the dr register as the threads have been switched to another thread context